# Unity FishNet - No synchronic from Network Transform between client

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

Unity Fish net, all set up is done. And available to play around. Client and server can see each other spawn.

Question is client move a box , server and other client cannot see the movement.
But when server move the box, all the client can see the movement.
Here is the box component add, network observer is added too.
[box Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8qn.png)

I am using unity 2022.3.8f1

Comment: do note, fish net is not part of unity - you are trying to rely on finding someone here who uses it, why not ask in their forums/support?